# How do I remove the white frame around the photo in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I upload an Image in tkinter there is a white frame around the picture. I searched a lot but I didn't foud any answer.

Picture of the white frame:
[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()

root.geometry("1200x583")

root.resizable(0,0)

place_one=Image.open("p1.jpg")

place_one=place_one.resize((1200,583))

place_one_2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(place_one)

place=Label(root,image=place_one_2)

place.place(x=-2,y=0)

character=Image.open("m2.gif")

character=ImageTk.PhotoImage(character)

L1=Label(root,image=character)

L1.place(x=0,y=355)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do not use `import*` , Because it puts a lot of stuff into your namespace [Why it is bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)

Comment: i tried  writing this code without import* but it was like the past.

Comment: Problem is with `borderwidth`

Comment: Read up on [`Label.config-method`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method) and set **all** defaults, `borderwidth`, `pad*`, ..., to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set image border width (`borderwidth`) ,

```
L1=Label(root,image=character, borderwidth=0)
```

---

Edit:
Do not use `import *`([why it is bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)) try to,

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("1200x583")
root.resizable(0,0)

place_one=Image.open("p1.jpg")
place_one=place_one.resize((1200,583))
place_one_2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(place_one)

place=tk.Label(root,image=place_one_2)

0place.place(x=-2,y=0)

character=Image.open("m2.gif")
character=ImageTk.PhotoImage(character)

L1=tk.Label(root,image=character, borderwidth=0)
L1.place(x=0,y=355)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried to write with "import tkinter as tk".thank you.your code helped me.